# n-dimensional array - return values

Tags: php, recursion, multidimensional-array

Simplifying the question: having an array with bosses and subaltern of the company, this array has a variable depth for some branches.

EX:

```
Array (
[boss] => Array (
    [id] => boss
    [pid] => root
    [sub] => Array (
        [user1] => Array (
            [id] => user1
            [pid] => boss
            [sub] => Array (
                [user1_1] => Array (
                    [id] => user1_1
                    [pid] => user1
                )
            )
        [user2] => Array (
            [id] => user2
            [pid] => boss
            [sub] => Array (
                [user2_1] => Array (
                    [id] => user2_1
                    [pid] => user2
                )
                [user2_2] => Array (
                    [id] => user2_2
                    [pid] => user2
                )
            )
        )
    )
  )
)
```

Question: What is the most elegant way to parse every branch (with dynamic depth) of the array in order to extract/search some data from the array.

Is a recursive function the only method?

I also checked `array_walk_recursive()`, but I guess it cannot return values, it can only modify the array values or keys (when using with reference).

EDIT:

The extraction I am looking for: to collect all the bosses for a specific user, that means the direct boss and also the boss of the boss... and so on.

Comment: What kind of extraction do you want to achieve?

Comment: Can `[sub]` contain multiple elements? Such as `[sub] => Array([userX] => ..., [userY] => ...)`?

Comment: @razvan: yes it can, please see edited array from the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a stack based algorithm such as the one below:

```
function lookup_array($array, $needle) {
    $parents = array();
    $stack = array(reset($array));

    while ($stack) {
        $element = array_pop($stack);

        if ($element['id'] == $needle) {
            break;
        }
        else if (isset($element['sub'])) {
            $parents[] = $element['id'];
            $stack = array_merge($stack, array(array('id' => $element['id'])), $element['sub']);
        }
        else if (end($parents) == $element['id']) {
            array_pop($parents);
        }
    }

    return $parents;
}
```

It works as follows:

```
$parents = lookup_array($array, 'user2_1');
print_r($parents); // Array ( [0] => boss [1] => user2 )
```

[Click here for DEMO.](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/7yh-gzb)